# Are there currently any engines for compiling JavaScript to an standalone app with graphics support?

Tags: javascript, canvas, v8

Ive seen things like Mozilla Rhino, or using V8 internally. What I am really looking for however is a solution where I can basically write standalone Canvas apps for the PC. Titanium was ok, but I didn't like the end result. Basically Im looking for the ability to write PC client apps with graphics support using JS, that compile into an application. I don't want something where all resources are totally open for anyone just to take/change and re release as their own. Big picture is to have the option to monetize a game if I chose to. Is there currently anything like that out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach to my previous answer is to use [nodeWebkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit).

Here are the following benefits over the previous method which used QT.

- Requires no seperate IDE like QT
- Requires no boilerplate code at all like QT
- Very easy to pack up all dependencies and resources into a single executable
- Uses V8 and is updated regularly to stay current unlike QT's implementation

For canvas specifically I have used it for the game [grapple hero](http://grapplehero.com) and Rezoner has used it for his game [qbqbqb](http://qbqbqb.rezoner.net/). There are many more examples of its use in the wild. It is as of today the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe AIR 2.5 has support for the canvas tag. It uses Webkit, however it doesn't support somethings current Webkit browsers have. Such as video/audio tag, svg. Here is a **[decent list](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/articles/air_and_webkit.html)** of supported/unsupported features of the Webkit build in AIR.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think about using Adobe Air was under the assumption you could only use AS3. Also Steamworks will accept Air apps which is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for.

Comment: Awesome! Yea AIR isn't too bad of a solution. They do lock you out of some things in Webkit, but have alternatives via JS hooks to AS3. Also, you can use JS frameworks such as mootools/jQuery within your AIR app too. This link might be of some use http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/getting_started_air_js.html

Comment: Ok got a chance to work with this and was pretty disappointed with the end result. It worked well in terms of supporting everything.. but the air app distributes all of your source with it, making it impossible to monetize. The exe just seems to be an interpreter for the html file distributed with it. If they support encryption, or at least packaging the resources up in some package files or the executable this will be a viable solution.

Comment: well pretty much anything that you write with JS is going to show your JS source... That's kind of a gimmie, unless of course you're looking for something that will compile your JS/HTML/CSS into another language. Same goes for apps on WebOS or anything else that uses pure JS for that matter, you can view the source when you install/download it. You can still sell these things if you wish stating that it is closed source and any reproduction of your app is not allowed. You could use a tool called jsmin http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html or something similar to help protect your code

Comment: Minifying != protecting, you can just use a beautifier to view it. Basically my question is exactly what you said, I am looking for something that I could use js as the primary language, and have something like canvas to render to that would compile my source into an application. The code isn't even the biggest issue I could live with that and just minify, the main issue is resources. Paying an artist to make sprites etc, then just having them all easily accessible is not something I'm comfortable with. I want a way to monetize JS apps like you can do with flash basically.

Comment: No ones code or images is safe with a compiler. The compiler isn't what protects your assets, it's called `software licensing/copyright`. And I didn't not say that minifying == protecting, keyword I used was `help` protect. You should have been more through in your question and should have tested before marking a question as correct then deciding to test it later and marking it as incorrect. Also note, flash doesn't protect your images, so you're miss guiding people again requesting something like flash. There are plenty of tools out there to retrieve .swf information such as code and images..

Comment: Ill give back the answer, just because maybe it wasn't right to unmark it, but everyone who sees it as the answer just know your project is 100% open, other than that Air is a really good solution, and if Adobe fixes that it will be awesome.

Comment: Thanks, but no need to give back the answer if it does work for you. I understand why you removed it I was just stating that you should check to make sure it works before marking. Also, I've not tried this but, if your main issue is images out in the open and you're ok with jsmining or obfuscating your JS then mayyyybe, again not sure, you could have one swc/swf file that held all your image assets and load them in from that file. Here is a link for using .swf/.swc assets with JS in AIR http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ed9.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather old question, but I wanted to give an updated answer to what I found. You can use QT to do exactly this. You include a webkit widget in the window, and load your js/html/images via resource files which are embedded into the application.

http://www.somethinghitme.com/2012/03/29/turning-canvas-games-into-executables/

I like this solution over the Air solution, because all of your assets can be contained and hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I would try [XULRunner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XULRunner). I use it whenever I don't feel like coding a whole application, and it works quite well. XUL is an XML-like markup language which is used for layout. Here's some example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window id="vbox example" title="Example 3...."
xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <vbox>
    <button id="yes" label="Yes"/>
    <button id="no" label="No"/>
    <button id="maybe" label="Maybe"/>
  </vbox>
</window>
```

CSS is used for styling the application, and JavaScript for the backend. It's quite easy to code with, and the whole application is like a standalone website. I coded a few download managers with it, but you can just migrate your HTML `<canvas>` straight into the code with minimal modifications.

To build an application, you just place the layout and functionality files into a folder, optionally make a JAR out of it, and just copy it into the XULRunner directory. You just run the executable, and it's good to go. Best of all, the same code works in Windows, Mac OS, and Linux.

Good luck!

(Here's the best reference for XULRunner, since it's Mozilla's baby: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xulrunner)

---

Wait, are you talking about the iPhone? You should have tagged that if you are... XULRunner is *only* available for every platform except iOS. Doesn't that make you love Apple?

Comment: Nope PC, just edited my question a bit to make that more clear. XULRunner looks ok actually Ill definitely have to look more into it.

Comment: Okay, I was just not used to people calling Windows applications Apps... I'll post some examples later.

Comment: Just as a second thought, try WebGL. It's OpenGL for web platforms, and it works with the trunk build of XULRunner. It looks amazing: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/.

Answer (score 0):

[jslibs](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/) is a standalone JavaScript runtime (based on Firefox JavaScript engine) that support OpenGL (and a lot of other 3rd party libraries).